# Convert enum TagLib::ID3v2::AttachedPictureFrame::Type to string?

Tags: c++, taglib

I am working with the taglib for c++. If I use the following code:

```
ID3v2::AttachedPictureFrame::Type t = picFrame->type();
```

I get for example "FrontCover (3)", but I did not find any solution to convert it to a string, to save the value.

I need also a solution how to set `ID3v2::AttachedPictureFrame::Type t` to write it to the APIC tag.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation of [`TagLib::ID3v2::AttachedPictureFrame`](https://taglib.org/api/classTagLib_1_1ID3v2_1_1AttachedPictureFrame.html) says that `Type` is an enum defined in that class:

> ```
> enum      Type {
>   Other = 0x00, FileIcon = 0x01, OtherFileIcon = 0x02, FrontCover = 0x03,
>   BackCover = 0x04, LeafletPage = 0x05, Media = 0x06, LeadArtist = 0x07,
>   Artist = 0x08, Conductor = 0x09, Band = 0x0A, Composer = 0x0B,
>   Lyricist = 0x0C, RecordingLocation = 0x0D, DuringRecording = 0x0E, DuringPerformance = 0x0F,
>   MovieScreenCapture = 0x10, ColouredFish = 0x11, Illustration = 0x12, BandLogo = 0x13,
>   PublisherLogo = 0x14
> }
> ```

There's no automatic conversion to convert an `enum`s symbol to a `std::string` or vice versa. Also as you noticed there's no such functionality provided by the `TagLib::ID3v2::AttachedPictureFrame` class.
You need to implement helper functions for that:

```
std::string attachedPictureFrameType2String(AttachedPictureFrame::Type type) {
    switch(type) {
    case AttachedPictureFrame::Other: return "Other";
    case AttachedPictureFrame::FileIcon: return "FileIcon";
    case AttachedPictureFrame::OtherFileIcon: return "OtherFileIcon";
    case AttachedPictureFrame::FrontCover: return "FrontCover";
    // All the other enum values ...
    }
}

AttachedPictureFrame::Type string2AttachedPictureFrameType(const std::string& s) {
    if(s == "Other") return AttachedPictureFrame::Other;
    if(s == "FileIcon") return AttachedPictureFrame::FileIcon;
    if(s == "OtherFileIcon") return AttachedPictureFrame::OtherFileIcon;
    if(s == "FrontCover") return AttachedPictureFrame::FrontCover;
    // All the other valid string values ...
    throw std::exception("Invalid string");
}
```

---

As mentioned by [@Uriya Harpeness](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14273548/uriya-harpeness) in their [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64108305/convert-enum-taglibid3v2attachedpictureframetype-to-string/64108620?noredirect=1#comment113366969_64108620) it's also possible to use a dictionary to do that, e.g.:

```
 using std::pair<AttachedPictureFrame::Type,std::string> = TypeDictItem;
 using std::vector<TypeDictItem> = TypeDict;
 const TypeDict pictureFrameTypeDict = { 
       std::make_pair(AttachedPictureFrame::Other,"Other")
     , std::make_pair(AttachedPictureFrame::FileIcon,"FileIcon")
     , std::make_pair(AttachedPictureFrame::OtherFileIcon,"OtherFileIcon")
     , std::make_pair(AttachedPictureFrame::FrontCover,"FrontCover")
     // ...
 };

 std::string attachedPictureFrameType2String(AttachedPictureFrame::Type type) {
     auto found = std::find_if(std::begin(pictureFrameTypeDict),
         std::end(pictureFrameTypeDict), 
         [type](const TypeDictItem& i) { return i.first == type; } );
     if(found != pictureFrameTypeDict.end()) {
          return (*found).second;
     }
     throw std::exception("Unexpected enum value.");
 }

 AttachedPictureFrame::Type string2AttachedPictureFrameType(const std::string s) {
     auto found = std::find_if(std::begin(pictureFrameTypeDict),
         std::end(pictureFrameTypeDict), 
         [s](const TypeDictItem& i) { return i.second == s; } );
     if(found != pictureFrameTypeDict.end()) {
          return (*found).first;
     }
     throw std::exception("Invalid string.");
 }
```

Comment: You can create a dict to map values to string representations, that way you can define it once and use for both directions.

Comment: @UriyaHarpeness Yes, that's anoher way to do it. Why don't you write another answer demonstrating that technique?

Comment: Sorry, answering through my phone... but I have used a few times a dict for bidirectional translation of objects and strings.

Comment: @UriyaHarpeness I've adopted your idea and added it to my answer. Note that not using a std::map is intentional, because of avoiding unnecessary overhead.

Comment: Thank you, I got it working. But I don't understand why it is so complicated. In my opinion would it much easier, when it would be possible to get only the numeric value of the type info.

Comment: @HGA It was you saying you need a string? You already get the numeric value from the `type()` getter, it's just an enum value, and restricted to these listed names and values. You can easily cast these to an `int`, `uintt_8`, or whatever you need. Just the other way round, it's not so safe. Casting from a number to an `enum` is possible, but if it's none of the predefined values, you'll get in trouble. May I ask what exactly you need to do with the values obtained with `type()`?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ in my opinion it would be easier to understand, if just the byte could be read, e.g. 0x03 for FrontCover, which could easy used with a switch. And on the other way just set type with using 0x03 for writing the type.

Comment: @HGA As you see in my answer, you already can use the `AttachedPictureFrame::Type` `enum` easily in a switch. Same for writing into the `AttachedPictureFrame::setType()` function. Honestly, I don't get your concerns. Maybe a misconception what `enum`s are? These **are easier to understand**, or would you prefer to memorize that `0x03` means the same as `AttachedPictureFrame::FrontCover`?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ maybe our thinging is a little bit different.You are right, in terms of memorize, but in my opinion it would be easier to implement, if I only had to write 0x03 and not FrontCover. If it would return an string, it would be also easier to undersand and save some programming work. But anyway I have it now understood and successful implemented. Thank you very much for your help.